# iOS location icon

Tags: ios, icons, location

everyone. I don't know whether you used app name Moves or not. If not,you can to download from app store. And you can find a issue, that display gps icon in status bar always(even though app was killed). At "Setting-privacy-location service",if you turn off the app,icon disappear. Turn on again, icon purple display. Why purple display,app is updating location?

Answer (score 3):

If an app uses, for example, [significant change service](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW8), the icon stays on even if the app is killed (because with significant change service, the app will be automatically re-awaken when iOS determines that a significant change has taken place; i.e. the iOS is effectively still tracking your location on behalf of the app, even though the app has been manually terminated). This is the documented behavior of significant change service, which, while less accurate than can be rendered by standard location services, continues tracking you even after the app has been terminated. The purple icon of location services won't be turned off until the app explicitly disables significant change service, or the app has been uninstalled.